# Salesforce MC - How to data extract in UTF8 to FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-extract, encoding

I'm having problems trying to export a data extension from Salesforce Marketing Cloud to FTP.

I created an Automation to extract this file, but I want to extract in UTF-8, my database only import files in this format.

So, how can I convert my data extract to UTF-8, instead of UTF-16?

I've tried to add a new Data Extract Activity, using ExtractType: Custom UTF-16 to UTF-8 Encoding. But that it isn't working, occur an error in this activity. I've fund that some guy did a [File Convert](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246329/marketing-cloud-data-extract-into-the-correct-file-encoding-format/267839#267839), but I can not find that option in my Salesforce Marketing Cloud Business Unit.

Comment: Here is that guy :D with that file convert. It needs three steps: 1 dataextraxt of dataextension, 2: dataextraction option file convert, 3 File Export. Can you specify what you do not find?

Comment: Hi Johannes, thanks for the reply. I didnt get the "File Convert" step. When I created the second Data Extract, i can't find the option "File Convert" in Extract Type. There is 6 options: Data Extention Extract (step1), Security Action Audit Log, Zip, Security Event Audit Log, Custom UTF16 to UTF8 Encoding, Tracking Extract. Can you show me where can I find this "File Convert", please? Thank you.

Comment: Data extract -> properties -> extract type = there you will find file convert. After that comes configuration where you can select utf8. Ask support when you do not see this option.

Comment: File Convert is something that Support enables as data extract type, along others.
( move, delete, gzip,...)

Please let us know if File Convert to UTF8 it works, I have used it in the past but recently had an issue with it that I could not explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some screenshots of an UTF8 DataExtract Activity:

[image]
[image]
[image]