# How could I find the exact row size of a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm trying to reduce the Data Extensions row size to 8000 bytes as Salesforce recommend but I have problems to know current exact size of a big DE I have.

Is there any way to calculate this? Through SQL, for example...

If not, it shouldn't be too difficult to sum up all columns sizes but then I would need to know size of different data types:

- Boolean: 1
- Date: ??
- Decimal with 8.2 precision??
- Number ??

Thanks

Comment: Now, in fact, looking for the 8000 bytes limits, I have found 4000 as the limit, here https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317499&type=1,

Comment: In this article they talk about 8000 characters https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_optimize_the_query_activity.htm&type=5, so now I also have the doubt about characters/bytes relationship... does a character fits into just 1 byte?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then marketing cloud encodes in UTF-16, where a character takes up two bytes (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267842/salesforce-mc-how-to-data-extract-in-utf8-to-ftp). That together with the max length the UI enforces (4000 chars) leads me to believe that one of the two articles is in error, and that the intended statement is 4000 chars / 8000 bytes.

Comment: I agree, I though that but, as you say, documentation is confusing on this matter. If I end involving Salesforce support I will show them this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can determine a data extension's size through REST API, by its objectID:

`GET {{restEndpoint}}/email/v1/dataextensions/YOURDATAEXTENSIONOBJECTID/filesize`

Headers

`Content-Type:application/json`

`Authorization: Bearer {{accessToken}}`

which returns the size in bytes:

```
{
"customObjectId": "YOURDATAEXTENSIONOBJECTID",
"filesize": 7430
}
```

This is of course on DE level, not row level, but using this basic method you can isolate separate effects (number of fields, types of fields, number of rows), by playing with different data extension setups and changing only one thing at a time and observing the effects. I haven't done this myself but those tests and results would be interesting.

Sidenote: To get the ObjectID first (which is not the customer Key) you have to retrieve the DE, say, by name, which you can do e.g. via SOAP API.

`POST {{soapEndpoint}}/Service.asmx`

Headers

`Content-Type:text/xml`

`SOAPAction: "Retrieve"`

Body

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
<RetrieveRequest>
<ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
<Properties>Name</Properties>
<Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
<Properties>ObjectId</Properties>
<Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
<q1:Property>Name</q1:Property>
<q1:SimpleOperator>equals</q1:SimpleOperator>
<q1:Value>NAME OF YOUR DE</q1:Value>
</Filter>
</RetrieveRequest>
</RetrieveRequestMsg>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks very much but this is not answering my question. I need to know the row size attending to fields definition. I need this to try adjusting to this best practices https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317499&type=1 (Any Data Extension spanning a cumulative field width greater than 4000 characters must be avoided)

Comment: Hi, what I meant was: why not set up a DE with one field of type Boolean, and retrieve its size? Then compare this to another DE with just a text field of length 1, ... rinse and repeat for other types?

Comment: oh! I missed that. OK, it's a solution. And perhaps I can make a copy of my DE and try your solution for empty table, with only one minimum data row and with a full data row. Thanks!

Comment: precisely :) Can you let us know the results when done?

Comment: Hi Jonas! well, I've made some tests but I'm not sure if they are going to be useful. I created an empty DE with only one bool field, it's filesize is 0. If I add 1 record with true then file size is 15, but if I add a record with false then file size is 16. 2 records will be around 22 depending on values and 3 records around 28. Filesize depends on the actual field value!

Comment: Then I made another DE with only 1 text(50) field then with 1 record with 1 char value filesize is 17, 1 record with 50 chars has 66, 2 records with 50 chars has 118 and 3 records with 50 chars values file size is 170. So each row is getting 52 bytes, I guess this is UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks. This is a pretty wild mix. Honestly, I would then try to do this on a usecase level (=  Take your particular Data Extension, and take a couple sample rows, average their sizes out.) Then work with approximations. generally speaking, follow generic best practices, e.g. "no more than 50 fields", see this doc on page 7: https://docplayer.net/134385397-The-data-handbook-data-architecture-for-salesforce-marketing-cloud-eliot-harper.html

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess I will make some assumptions on the number and date fields size and will try to calculate the row size as an estimate, based on the big numbers, which come from text fields.

Comment: And, just to help. It's easier to get the id of a data extension using "Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Developer Tools" chrome extension.

Comment: sounds good enough to me :) can you mark the answer as accepted if it helped you in the end?

Comment: Also, I heard in a seminar (in YouTube)  that the limitation is just for text fields so this would make this question pointless.